# Javascript singleton class default value

Tags: javascript, singleton

How can I set a default value in my singleton class. I have this dictionary in my class where the variable name "myVar" is assigned a value of 3. However, running this code below does not return a value of 3, instead it returns undefined.

```
init = function() {
   var var1 = Singleton.myVar;
   console.log(var1); // Returns undefined
   var1 = 3;
   console.log(var1);; // Returns 3
   var var2 = Singleton.myVar;
   console.log(var2); // Returns undefined
}
```

Singleton Class:

```
 var Singleton = (function(){
        var instantiated;
        function init (){
            // all singleton code goes here
            return {
                myVar: 3,
                publicWhatever:function(){
                    alert('whatever')
                },
                publicProperty:2
            }
        }

        return {
            getInstance :function(){
                if (!instantiated){
                    instantiated = init();
                }
                return instantiated; 
            }
        }
    })()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `getInstance` function to get your singleton instance :

```
 var var1 = Singleton.getInstance().myVar;
```

Note that your factory seems overly complicated. I see the point in using [an IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (you could define additional private fields or functions) but you could use an IIFE and reduce your singleton factory to

```
var Singleton = (function(){
  return {
    myVar: 3,
    publicWhatever:function(){
      alert('whatever')
    },
    publicProperty:2
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why is your singleton declaration a function at all? Why not just declare the object directly, like so:

```
var Singleton = {
    myVar: 3,
    publicWhatever:function(){
      alert('whatever')
    },
    publicProperty:2
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
var Singleton = function() {

    return {
       ...
       myVar: 3,
       ...
    }

})();
```

Rather than have another layer inside the singleton?